# Две крайние операции: нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, жаргон

Появилась статья «Успехи России и т. д»: https://metayogg.com/articles/moskva-byot-arktikoj-po-gegemonii-ssha/. Цитата:

> Только две крайние российские операции в Сирии и Арктике подстегнули
>   науку и промышленность страны куда больше, чем все слова и действия...

Понятно, что мнительность или суеверие некоторых вычеркнула слово *последний* из их профессиональной жизни. Но стоит ли (так) закреплять в публицистике подобный сленг?

Answer (score 4):

Не стоит, конечно, может быть, этот блоггер и публицист Хубиев был военным, лётчиком например? Тогда бы это было объяснимо. Но и кавычки здесь, по-моему, тоже не нужны.
В публицистике сленг вообще неуместен.

Answer (score 2):

Ну да, суеверие. Особенно у военных. У моряков и врачей - то же. И у лётчиков.

В публицистике следовало бы сохранить нормативное "последний" и в скобочках добавить:

или, как принято говорить в армейских кругах, крайний.

*Только две последние (или, как то принято на сленге военных, "крайние") российские операции в Сирии и Арктике подстегнули науку и промышленность страны куда больше, чем все слова и действия...*

Answer (score 2):

В обычной языковой среде это может восприниматься с недоумением: то ли это диалектное "кто крайний", то ли дело в "геометрии" крайнего севера и юга, раз там и про Арктику говорится. Автору надо было отвлечься от привычного круга общения, где такие выражения привычны (можно предположить, что термином "крайняя операция" пользуются штабные офицеры): судя по общему стилю, материал ориентирован на широкого читателя. Личное же суеверие проще снять употреблением слова "недавний". В целом текст написан складно, что контрастирует с множеством пунктационных ошибок.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше подобрать **более подходящий для нейтрального стиля синоним**:

**Всего только (всего лишь)** две **недавние** российские операции в Сирии и Арктике подстегнули науку и промышленность страны куда больше, чем все слова и действия...

1) Кавычки, пояснения разного рода могут отвлекать внимание читателя от основной темы.

2) Желательно конкретизировать смысл многозначного слова ***только***.

ТОЛЬКО. I. частица. 1. Не более как, всего лишь.   2. Единственно, исключительно.